# jQuery AJAX load IE6 issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous, load

I have a main HTML file with all the jQuery and JavaScript files included in it. Now I have a table which has a expand/collapse functionality. This table is in a different HTML file.

I am trying to load the table in the main file. I was successful in loading the table in the main HTML file but the expand/collapse is not working only in IE6/IE7. This works fine in FF, Chrome, Safari and IE8.

local.js has the expand/collapse code
table.html is the html file which has only the table code and no JavaScript.

**MAIN HTML:**

```
<html>
    <title>Main html</title>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" scr="localjs.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            $('#ajaxtable').load('ajax/table.html', function() {
                alert('Table Loaded.');
            });

        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="ajaxtable"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I can see the table gets loaded in the ajaxtable div but the expand/collapse is not working only in IE6.

Comment: what `expand/collapse` ? Where's the code?

Comment: There's nothing in the code you posted that has anything at all to do with expanding or collapsing.

Comment: Sorry about that. The code for expand/collapse is given below:  $('table tr.heading').click(function(){
       $(tr.alpha).slideToggle('slow');
       
    });  This code is in localjs.js

Comment: You are loading `localjs.js` before the `$('#ajaxtable')` call, which means it is trying to attach the click handler to an element that hasn't been created yet.  So of course it will not work.

Comment: IE6?? You supporting Mosiac and Netscape too?

Comment: well i'm not a fan of IE but unfortunately have to support IE6

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in my comment above, you are loading `localjs.js` before the `$('#ajaxtable')` call. Attach the click handler after the table has been created and you should be fine...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#ajaxtable').load('ajax/table.html', function() {
  alert('Table Loaded.');
  $('table tr.heading').click(function(){ $(tr.alpha).slideToggle('slow'); });
});
</script>
```